# Text Area do not append if button is clicked in java

Tags: java

I have designed a GUI with JTextArea and two buttons is in it. Whenever i click a button some text in TextArea do not append until execution of the complete function is completed.

When the listener calls the startAnimation method, a star should be printed and then sleep method is called, then again another star must be appended in the text area and again sleep back and forth. What happens here is that no text appears in text area once i click the button. soon the startAnimation method ends. Suddenly all the stars appear in textArea. Any help??

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;


@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Gui extends JFrame 
{
JTextArea console = null;
JButton start     = null;
JButton exit      = null;
Listener listen   = null;

public Gui() 
{
    // Initializing the Frame
    setSize(300,400);
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    // Initializing Components
    console = new JTextArea(20,20);
    start   = new JButton("Start");
    exit    = new JButton("Exit");
    listen  = new Listener(this);

    // Adding Components
    getContentPane().add(console);
    getContentPane().add(start);
    getContentPane().add(exit);

    // Adding Listeners
    exit.addActionListener(listen);
    start.addActionListener(listen);

    // Setting properties of frame
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    //pack();
}

public void sleep()
{
    for(long i = 0 ; i < 9999999 ; i++);
}

public void startAnimation()
{

    for(int i = 0 ; i < 19 ; i++)
    {   
        for(int j = 0 ; j < 40 ; j++)
        {
            console.append("*");
                            sleep();

        }
        console.append("\n");
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    Gui myGUI = new Gui();
}

}
```

Listener Class

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;


public class Listener implements ActionListener 
{
Gui temp = null;

public Listener(Gui temp) 
{
    this.temp = temp;
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) 
{
    if(event.getSource() == temp.exit)

        System.exit(0);

    else
    {
        temp.start.setEnabled(false);
        temp.startAnimation();

    }

}

}
```

Comment: can you elaborate your problem

Comment: I ran your code it is displaying stars after click of button.What is the problem ?

Comment: When the listener calls the startAnimation method, a start should be printed and then sleep method is called, then again another star must be appended in the text area and again sleep back and forth. What happens here is that no text appears in text area once i click the button. soon the startAnimation method ends. Suddenly all the stars appear in textArea.

Comment: All the stars must not appear in one go. One star at a time and then sleep. Add another star to the previous stars and then sleep till the end. But it is printing all stars in one go

Comment: You are not calling your `sleep()` method at all. And BTW, better use Java built-in `sleep()` method instead.

Comment: Even if i call sleep(); No good at all.I have modified the code as well now (calling sleep method).